# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 prevent auth cookie expiration

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I'm working on an application (**ASP.NET MVC 5**) where I want to prevent auth cookie expiration on a specific page (It's a huge form and it takes some time to fill in completely). What I have is:

ASP.NET Identity configuration in **Startup.cs**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, Guid>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
            getUserIdCallback: (id) => Guid.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
    },
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
});
```

**SignIn** method implementation in a Controller

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    AllowRefresh = true,
    IsPersistent = isPersistent,
    ExpiresUtc = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
}, identity);
```

**jQuery** method implementation on a specific page that makes post to a server each 10 minutes.

```
(function ($) {

    function keepSessionAlive() {
        $.post("/Resources/KeepSessionAlive");
    }

    // 10 minutes
    setInterval(keepSessionAlive, 60 * 1000 * 10);

})(jQuery);
```

**KeepSessionAlive** implementation in the Controller

```
//
// POST: /Resources/KeepSessionAlive/
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult KeepSessionAlive()
{
    if (HttpContext.Session != null)
        HttpContext.Session["KeepSessionAlive"] = DateTime.Now;
    return Json($"Last refresh {DateTime.Now.ToString("O")}");
}
```

**Problem:**
When I navigate to the specific page, I can see the following post requests:

1. /Resources/KeepSessionAlive - 200 OK
2. /Resources/KeepSessionAlive - 200 OK
3. /Resources/KeepSessionAlive - 401 Unauthorized

But after 30 minutes I get 401 unauthorized. What I'm doing wrong?

Btw. What is difference between **CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan** and **AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc**. It must be same? How it behaves if I set them to different values? Thanks for clarification.

// EDIT:

I've found out that cookie expires after 15 minutes that is equal to `validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)`, but I thought it does not affect cookie expiration because `this is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand it but when I've set up `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan` and `AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc` to the same value (30 minutes), it's started to work.

The final source code:

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, Guid>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
            getUserIdCallback: (id) => Guid.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
    }
});
```

**SignIn**

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { 
  IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

**jQuery**

```
function keepSessionAlive() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "/Resources/KeepSessionAlive",
        success: function (result) {
            console.debug("keepSessionAlive response [" + result + "]");
            window.setTimeout(keepSessionAlive, 60 * 1000 * 15); // 15 minutes
        }
    });
}
keepSessionAlive();
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and my .aspnet.applicationcookie wasn't refreshing it's expiration time, but setting the SlidingExpiration CookieAuthenticationOptions' to true solved it for me.